# Sampling from the Transition Kernel

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ be a probability space. Assume that $K(x,A) : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to [0,1]$ is a Transition Kernel, i.e., for every fixed $x$, $K$ is a probability measure and for every fixed $A$, $K$ is measurable.

Suppose, $Y$ is a given random variable and $\Sigma_Y$ be the sigma algebra generated by $Y$. Then, is it possible to obtain some random variable $Z$ such that $E[f(Z)|\Sigma_Y] (\omega) = \int f K(Y(\omega),\bullet)$, $P$-a.s. for every $f$ in some nice class of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

A [textbook](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=hE3KF5Wf6ecC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) I am reading says $Z \sim K(Y,\bullet)$ and then uses the above equality for all $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (bounded continuous functions).

Thanks,

P.S. Most probably this follows from existence of Markov Processes for a given transition kernel.